# python: is there any way for a python program to be displayed as a normal app?

Tags: python, windows

I am creating a game in python using PyGame. I had an idea, and was wondering if it is possible for the script to have a "shortcut" displayed on the desktop, and for it to appear in a similar way to actual apps.

For example, the way apps appear in a phone, such as chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have done that... All you have to do is create a shortcut of the python file, and move it to the desktop directory. I have attached a screenshot of the icon on the desktop.

[image: Python Shortcut]

or if you have already finished developing, use Pyinstaller to convert it to an executable(*.exe) which is your normal windows app format. It will run on all Windows PCs, even without Python installed.
Here is a screenshot of a python app that I have made into an executable.

[image: Pressure Coverter.exe]

Here is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/TheBoss313/infuriating-games) with a few games that I have made and uploaded as executables. It also has code for a simple but annoying Discord bot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to change the icon of a shortcut.
Here is how:

[image]

You can download many other icons, or even create your own.