# How to install Python script on another system and run it in background?

Tags: python, installation, windows-10

I have a python script which does small automation of starting and stopping Windows service using keyboard shortcuts.

This is the code which does it:

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This works fine when I run it manually.

Is it possible to "install" this as a service in Windows 10 and run it on windows start? I mean is there a way to put it in something like exe file and give to someone so he/she can install it on his/her PC and be able to use these shortcuts?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64893357/13552470) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module like `auto-py-to-exe`
(https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

It works really well and you can make a standalone .exe with it.